# Can I use Azure Network Security Group to Allow Access to Database VM only from Web Apps?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans, azure-nsg

I would like to close MySQL port on the VM to all connections except from Web Apps. Can this be done?
The settings below do close MySQL port, yet don't allow Web Apps to connect.
[image]

Comment: What is order number for deny rule?

Comment: I didn't create a deny rule, it was created automatically. DenyAllInBound with priority 65500.

Comment: Has the web app integrated into a subnet?

Comment: No it isn't. There is nothing in the description of Service Tag that indicates that would be required.

Answer (score 0):

Your webapp will have a Public IP assigned. You may try the IP as the source with a rule saying that allow only from the IP selected

Comment: I'd like to avoid that. We have a lot of Web Apps and we will be creating and removing a lot of them. So this approach would require heave and complex automation of getting those IPs and whitelisting them, then removing IPs, when Web Apps will be deleted.